# dynamic LotusScript multi dimensional arrays

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I was just doing some yicky code and I thought, instead of using three dynamic arrays, as such:

dim x() as string, y()  as string, z() as string

It will be nicer to have a 3 dimensional dynamic array.  But; the help and my fumbling experiments has not revealed the method of defining them.

This does not work:

dim x()() or dim(,2) or dim(,)

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dynamic array is declared the same way regardless of the number of dimensions (arrays in LotusScript can have up to 8 dimensions). According to your example I think it is a two dimensional array you want, where the first dimension is limited to three entries.

If you first declare the array as:

```
Dim x() As String
```

You can then specify bounds according to the following example:

```
Redim x( 0 To 2, 0 To 9 ) ' A two dimensional array
```

And if you need to enlarge the array later (and keep all the values) you can do it like this:

```
Redim Preserve x( 0 To 2, 0 To 99 )
```

Please keep in mind that only the bounds of last dimension can be changed once the number of dimensions of the array has been set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lists instead of arrays.

```
Dim x list as String
```

That is fully dynamic and takes a string as index. List can't contain lists, but lists can contain objects, so you might want to do

```
Public Class ListContainer
   Public level2 List as String
End Class
```

This way you never need to REDIM preserve. A forall loops you savely through a list

Comment: Steve, Lists can contain Lists, if you assign a list to a variant then add that variant to your main List, it will work. Do this in a function and return that function to your list, eg: list(A) = buildlist(), in buildlist (dim as variant), you say dim b list as string, then return buildlist = b, build list b however, you want. I do this a lot and works fine.